# Remove all spaces in data skipping over header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a function that will find all spaces and remove them from my data, however, I need it to skip the first line in the excel sheet as that is the header line that needs to keep its spaces. For example, I have a column with the header `Power` with the column index of `5`, I want the function to search from column 5 row 2 to the last row with data in column 5 for spaces. If there are spaces that exist in the data, I want them to be removed and replaces with no space.

This is what I have tried so far, however, I cannot get it to remove the spaces when I test it.

```
Sub removespace()
    Range(2,5, cells(rows.Count,5).End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
    Range(cells(2,5), cells(rows.Count,5).End(xlUp)).Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Selecting only consumes Excel resources, not bringing any benefit...

A better idea would be to fully qualify the used range. Now, it works on the active sheet. If you want running on a different than the active one, you should do it as I am saying...

Comment: It is telling me there is a syntax error is a comma or something missing? An expected list separator or a )

Comment: @resu_student Yes, please use the updated answer. I did not test the code and missing an ending parenthesis...

Comment: I tested, unfortunately it is not removing the spaces in the data

Comment: @resu_student Did you refresh the page before copying the updated code? This one, I mean...

Comment: Yes, I copied it exactly

Comment: @resu_student Too many arguments and no time to check all of them now. Try it now, with minimum (necessary), please... I mean, the updated code.

Comment: No it is still not working, would the fact that my data is a hyperlink be causing the problem?

Comment: @resu_student Well, it depends... Is it a Formula hyperlink?

Comment: I just tested data as non hyperlink and the sub is still not removing spaces from regular text data

Comment: @resu_student The last attempt... It probably memorized the `xlWhole`, used before. Try it as it is now (using `xlPart`)... Theoretically it should solve every string, including the hyperlink formula 'frendly name'...

Comment: I added `xlPart` adjusting my code and it is still not removing the extra spaces from the data cells in the excel sheet.

Comment: @resu_student Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so and you accept a connection, I would like to connect and see what's happening in your case. It works as it should on my computer...

Comment: No I do not have that, could you provide an example of what your data looks like you are testing with?

Comment: @resu_student Firstly, are you sure that you want replacing spaces from column "E:E"? if so, the strings in my case are usual, like: "One two", "one two     three" and so on. I also placed a `Hyperlink` formula as `=HYPERLINK(Sheet156!A1,"my link")` and another hyperlink having 'Text to display` = "My second link". All of them are correctly processed by the above code.

Comment: I think I have found a solution to use the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute` to replace `" "` with `""`